# How to edit custom message in log files while creation

Tags: java, log4j

I am using slf4j for logging in my application. I have set 100 kb as the max size of my log file. But when, first time, the application starts, the log file is created and I am modifying the content with some user information. But when next time, the log file is created in middle of the application, those user information are not captured. Is there any way to enter own messages in log file whenever it is generated.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: That wouldn't be a feature of slf4j but of the backing logging framework. Example for log4j (but with static content): https://coderanch.com/t/535099/oa/Inserting-Header-Text-Log-file I am not sure if it is possible to add a dynamic header.

Comment: In log4j2, the PatternLayout has a `header` attribute to do this. But also static. Maybe you could change the config programmatically ...

Comment: Which logging framework is used? If it is log4j2 - you can find examples of static and dynamic here: http://www.codepreference.com/2016/04/extending-log4j2-format-with-plugins.html